# How to generate html code that also contains and runs php code in javascript (onclick event)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, concatenation

First of all, I know the question is kinda wrong itself cause php can't be run from the browser, but I ask it this way for you to understand what I need to achieve.

Well, my problem is very simple.
I got a form with some inputs. (Basically a form to create a recipe (name, type, veggie or not etc, and a list of ingredients)
And I want a button adding an input in the form everytime the user is clicking on it.
The problem is that the select input I need to be created contains php code that need to be run to get it's content and I obviously can't just append my input in the html.

I assume that I need to use AJAX but I never used this and I can't figure out how to proceed after hours of research cause I probably don't think about the right way to do it.

Well my code is like this :

HTML/PHP file:

```
    <form>
        // some inputs

        <select name="ingredient1" id="ingredients"> <!-- my select input for the first ingredient -->
            <?php 
            foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $ingredient['id']; ?>"><?php echo $ingredient['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <div id="add_ingredient_button"></div> <!-- the button with the onclick event -->

    </form>
```

JS :

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        let ingredientCount = 1

        const addIngredientInput = function () {

            ingredientCount++
            let newSelect = // here let's say I try to concatenate my html and php to get the exact same code than the select input above in the html code plus the right ingredient count to get ingredients2, ingredients3 etc..
            $('#add_ingredient_button').before(newSelect)
            return ingredientCount

            }

        $('#add_ingredient_button').on('click', function(){
            addIngredientInput()
        })

     });
```

Well, I know that's probably super messy and that it cannot work like this since php won't be run by the client and it obviously get inserted in the dom as a comment or in plain text anyway but I have no cluehow to generate what my input code in AJAX

Sorry for the struggling but I'm new to web developpement and I probably don't think about the right way

Thanks anyway for your time and answers

Comment: Recommend trying to change your mental model of how this could work. Have PHP be server side only code and javascript be client side. javascript requests data from PHP through ajax and then renders it once it returns. That PHP script that is building the select box could be building JSON to send back instead.

Comment: I struggle a lot thinking about how things could and should work. I assume it comes with experience or I'm screwed already ! 
But in that case I probably just didn't make myself clear enough about what I wanted to achieve cause client/server side is pretty obvious stuff. I knew I needed AJAX, I just don't know how to use it i that case but I guess I will explore a bunch of tutorial etc.. thanks anyway

Comment: It can be a rabbit hole. You have to decide how much you're willing to bite off at once. But the core fundamental piece of this mindset is that all of your HTML is in HTML/JavaScript and PHP is only sending data via JSON. Lumen is a great PHP framework for creating PHP services that send JSON. If you want to stick with jQuery there are a bunch of ajax getting started tutorials out there. If you want to bite off even more take a look at React. It will be repulsive at first but once you drink the koolaid you'll never look back.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same select-element with the same options, than you can simply clone the select-element. Like this:

HTML / PHP:

```
<div id="selectors_container">
 <select name="ingredient1" class="ingredients">
  [your PHP code]
 </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// select the last element by class and get the last child
var item = document.getElementByClass("ingredients").lastChild;
// Copy the element and its child nodes
var clone = item.cloneNode(true);
// Append the cloned element to your container
document.getElementById("selectors_container").appendChild(clone);
```

For more details you can take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp
or for an ajax request:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: It is not exactly the same cause I guess that I need to have a different name for each select so I can get every value at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

So im not sure exactly what you are trying to do. If you write PHP it is converted to html in the browser. that html can be retrieved using Jquery or vanilla. Therefore after a page is loaded and the html is created than you can retrieve the form value from a select/dropdown/input whatever.

the code I provided allows you to add a new input with the push of a button, change the select value and then print the final result. the final result can be converted to json and passed as a body parameter with ajax.

```js
let ingredientCount = 0;

$( document ).ready(function() {
      addInputEventListener();
      handleFormCompletion();

     });

const addInputEventListener = () => {
  $('#add-input').click(() => {
    ingredientCount += 1;
    $('#main-form').append(`<input name="ingredient-${ingredientCount}"></input>`)
  })
}

handleFormCompletion = () => {
  let ingredients = {}
  $('#print-ingredients').click(() => {
    ingredients['select'] = $('select[name="ingredients"]').val()
    $('input').each(i => {
      ingredients[$('input').eq(i).attr('name')] = $('input').eq(i).val()
    })
    console.log(ingredients)
    ///ajax post request here
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <form id="main-form">
    <select name="ingredients" form="main-form">
      <option value="organic">Organic</option>
      <option value="not organic">Not Organic</option>
      <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
      <option value="pickles">Pickles</option>
    </select>
   </form>
  <button type="button" id="add-input">add Input</button>
  <button type="button" id="print-ingredients">print Ingredients</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer.
I probably didn't explain it right. 
What I want it is very simple, but there is probably a better way to manage to do it so my sample was terrible.
Basically I have a php function that query all the ingredient from a table in my database.
And in my form I got one select with all that ingredient (php looping into the array that i get from query and displaying all the options in the select ) But since a recipe could have a lot more ingredient I want a button that add one select like this. But the php won't run anymore since js adds it after the page is loaded